# What exactly are the categories of intermolecular forces

Tags: forces, interactions, molecules

So I read the wikipedia and its catagorization is somewhat vague. (Link here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermolecular_force)

In wikipedia, the van der waals forces are quite clearly stated to include
keesom (permanent dipole - permanent dipole)
debye (permanent dipole - induced dipole)
london dispersion (fluctuating dipole - induced dipole)

and the attractive intermolecular forces include
hydrogen bonding
beta bonding (ionic bonding)
"Dipole–dipole and similar interactions"
van der waals forces

However, according to the description of keesom forces, shouldn't hydrogen bonding, beta bonding and "Dipole–dipole and similar interactions" be some kinds of keesom forces as well? If so, then is it correct to say that "the intermolecular forces include and only include keesom forces, debye forces and london dispersion forces"?